# Unable to parse date which is missing minutes?

Tags: java, date, java-time

I am trying to parse a date-time string that does not contain minutes 2019-10-12T07Z.

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        // 2019-10-12T07:00:00Z
    OffsetDateTime offSetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-10-12T07Z");
    System.out.println(offSetDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
    
    }
}
```

When I run the above code, it throws the following exception stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-10-12T07Z' could not be parsed at index 13
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:402)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:387)
    at com.test.offset.offset.App.main(App.java:16)
```

Expected output

```
2019-10-12T07:00:00Z
```

Any idea what I should do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java how to remove nth minute from given time string without considering time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50996844/java-how-to-remove-nth-minute-from-given-time-string-without-considering-time-zo)

Comment: You need to pass a DateTimeFormatter (with the correct format) to the parse() method.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-

Comment: Funnily ISO 8601 seems to allow the minutes to be absent (at least there is an example of just that [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times)), but the built-in formatters of java.time require them to be present (as you can also see from following links a few steps from the one provided by @PaulSamsotha).

Comment: @Emilio No, I think that that’s different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create custom [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) representing the time and offset.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHX");
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-10-12T07Z",formatter) ;

System.out.println( odt );  //2019-10-12T07:00Z
```

See that code [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/Vm4xfd).

> 2019-10-12T07:00Z

If you want to display the seconds, extract an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) to use its [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#toString()) method.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
System.out.println( instant ) ;  // 2019-10-12T07:00:00Z
```

> 2019-10-12T07:00:00Z

Comment: @basil bourque my expected output is 2019-10-12T07:00:00Z

Comment: @prasanth I added more to Deadpool's Answer. In one line: `OffsetDateTime.parse( "2019-10-12T07Z" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHX" ) ).toInstant().toString()`. Alternatively, you could define another `DateTimeFormatter` object with appropriate formatting pattern.

Answer (score -2):

This is what I usually do when I need date + timestamp

```
String dateFile = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(new java.util.Date());
String timeFile = new SimpleDateFormat("HH-mm").format(new java.util.Date());
```

Comment: You are using *terrible* date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community all gave up on those legacy classes. I suggest you do the same. See [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73560336/642706) by Deadpool.

Comment: Yep, but, in my scenario, that's the only way that worked for me. So, since I do not know the context of the application, I thought that was a good idea adding another way to do what the user needs.

Comment: This code produces different results depending on the JVM’s current default time zone. [See for yourself, at Ideone.com.](https://ideone.com/RczslP) `Asia/Tokyo: 09-01-2022 | 07-12. America/Edmonton: 08-31-2022 | 16-12`. Your accountants and auditors may not be happy to see invoices’ date and time jumping around, seemingly at random.

Comment: So, what do you suggest? How can I build a String with fileName + date + timestamp in a downloadable file name?  This is what I have today ->
`String fileName = clientDataObjectRequest.getMetricName().replaceAll("[ /]","_") + "_" + dateFile + "T" + timeFile;`

Comment: `String fileName = "whatever" +  "_" + OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ).format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmssZZZZZ") ) + ".txt" ;`  See code run on [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/37hFDB). This has been addressed many times already on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It’s not the only way that works, it’s the worst way, and as @BasilBourque says, whether it works depends. Even when you use bad code in your projects, please don’t spread it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also I don’t see that your answer has anything to do with answering the question as asked?