# Single date formatter to parse dates with different syntax

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I am having a java program . In my java program the input  will be  date strings of different formats like the following

```
a) 2021-10-09T08:00:01.111Z ( with millisecond)
b) 2021-10-09T08:00:01Z ( without milliseconds)
c) 2021-10-09T08:00Z ( no seconds )
d) 2021-10-09T08Z ( no minutes )
```

Currently I am using a built in date formatter **DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME** . However when i run my sample snippet program it fails

the following is my sample program

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Tester2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        OffsetDateTime t1 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-10-09T08:00:01.111Z");;
        System.out.println(t1.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
        
        OffsetDateTime t2 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-10-09T08:00:01Z");;
        System.out.println(t2.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
        
        OffsetDateTime t3 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-10-09T08:00Z");;
        System.out.println(t3.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
   
        OffsetDateTime t4 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-10-09T08Z");;
        System.out.println(t4.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
    }

}
```

However when I run my program it fails with the following output.

```
2021-10-09T08:00:01.111Z
2021-10-09T08:00:01Z
2021-10-09T08:00:00Z
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-10-09T08Z' could not be parsed at index 13
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2052)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1954)
    at java.base/java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:404)
    at java.base/java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:389)
    at test.Tester2.main(Tester2.java:20)
```

The following is the output I want

```
2021-10-09T08:00:01.111Z
2021-10-09T08:00:01Z
2021-10-09T08:00:00Z
2021-10-09T08:00:00Z
```

Is there any java built in data formatter that will help me to achieve the desired output. If there is no such dateformatter could you help me to write a new date formatter ? Another solutions are welcome.

Comment: The ideal solution is to educate the publisher of your data about the advantages of using only the fully-expanded formats defined in ISO 8601.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to parse date which is missing minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73559990/unable-to-parse-date-which-is-missing-minutes)

Comment: ISO 8601 is terrible, java.time is terrible, only unix timestamp rocks!

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I hope that was meant as irony?

Comment: @OleV.V. definitely not, that is sad truth. I do not see any difference between passing "only the fully-expanded formats defined in ISO 8601" and unix timestamps, except the last one option is more reliable.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov It’s no truth, it’s a controversial personal opinion. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @OleV.V. The problem is "ISO 8601" is the standard, you either support it fully or do not support, lecturing people to use "only the fully-expanded formats defined in ISO 8601" is the same as lecturing them that Java do not support standards.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Java does not support the full ISO 8601 standard. whether it should is debatable, I guess, I understand why it wasn’t decided that it should. Depending on the situation I usually would not agree that one should educate someone to use only the full forms (whichever they are). I much prefer ISO 8601 over Unix timestamps and I think most find ISO more readable.

Comment: @OleV.V. and what is the profit from that readability if machine fails to parse data? btw, have you read [follow-up Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73596075?noredirect=1#comment129971079_73596816)? I do believe TC is now counting characters in input string and trying to apply some heuristics, instead of ditching time api as I have suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247824/discussion-between-ole-v-v-and-andrey-b-panfilov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataTimeFormatter` supports optional parsing patterns with `[` and `]` characters.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH[:mm[:ss[.SSS]]]X");

    OffsetDateTime t1 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-10-09T08:00:01.111Z", formatter);
    System.out.println(t1.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));

    OffsetDateTime t2 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-10-09T08:00:01Z", formatter);
    System.out.println(t2.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));

    OffsetDateTime t3 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-10-09T08:00Z", formatter);
    System.out.println(t3.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));

    OffsetDateTime t4 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-10-09T08Z", formatter);
    System.out.println(t4.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
```

Output is what you asked for:

```
2021-10-09T08:00:01.111Z
2021-10-09T08:00:01Z
2021-10-09T08:00:00Z
2021-10-09T08:00:00Z
```

Comment: is it possible to make hours also optional ? thank you . anyway great solution

Comment: It is impossible to parse `OffsetDataTime` without any time value.

Answer (score 0):

One the one hand that might look weird that Java lacks functionality of parsing partial date formats (I'm facing such issues in every heterogeneous project), however, on the other hand when we parsing partial date formats we need somehow compensate missing fields, and the problem is such compensations/heuristics depend on either particular project or, moreover, particular interaction between systems, please check the PoC below, hope it will help:

```java
import static java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY;
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR;
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND;
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE;

public class DateTimeFormats {

    public static final DateTimeFormatter ISO_LOCAL_TIME = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendFraction(NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 9, true)
            .toFormatter();

    public static final DateTimeFormatter ISO_OPTIONAL_TIME = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendLiteral('T')
            .append(ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
            .parseStrict()
            .toFormatter();

    public static final DateTimeFormatter ISO_OPTIONAL_OFFSET = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendOffsetId()
            .toFormatter();

    public static final DateTimeFormatter ISO_LOCAL_DATE_OPTIONAL_TIME = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .appendOptional(ISO_OPTIONAL_TIME)
            .toFormatter();

    public static final DateTimeFormatter ISO_DATE_OPTIONAL_TIME = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(ISO_LOCAL_DATE_OPTIONAL_TIME)
            .appendOptional(ISO_OPTIONAL_OFFSET)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendLiteral('[')
            .parseCaseSensitive()
            .appendZoneRegionId()
            .appendLiteral(']')
            .toFormatter()
            // compensation
            .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .withChronology(IsoChronology.INSTANCE);

    public static OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime(CharSequence text) {
        return offsetDateTime(text, ISO_DATE_OPTIONAL_TIME);
    }

    public static OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime(CharSequence text, DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(formatter, "formatter");
        return formatter.parse(text, DateTimeFormats::offsetDateTime);
    }

    public static OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime(TemporalAccessor temporal) {
        try {
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.from(temporal);
            Optional<LocalTime> time = Optional.ofNullable(temporal.query(TemporalQueries.localTime()));
            Optional<ZoneOffset> offset = Optional.ofNullable(temporal.query(TemporalQueries.offset()));
            Optional<ZoneId> zone = Optional.ofNullable(temporal.query(TemporalQueries.zoneId()));
            // compensation
            LocalDateTime result = LocalDateTime.of(date, time.orElse(LocalTime.MIN));
            if (offset.isPresent()) {
                return OffsetDateTime.of(result, offset.get());
            } else if (zone.isPresent()) {
                return ZonedDateTime.of(result, zone.get())
                        .toOffsetDateTime();
            }
            return result
                    // compensation
                    .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                    .toOffsetDateTime();
        } catch (DateTimeException ex) {
            throw new DateTimeException("Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: " +
                    temporal + " of type " + temporal.getClass().getName(), ex);
        }

    }

}
```

```java
System.out.println(offsetDateTime("2021-10-09T08:00:01.1111111Z"));
System.out.println(offsetDateTime("2021-10-09T08:00:01.111Z"));
System.out.println(offsetDateTime("2021-10-09T08:00:01Z"));
System.out.println(offsetDateTime("2021-10-09T08:00Z"));
System.out.println(offsetDateTime("2021-10-09T08Z"));
System.out.println(offsetDateTime("2021-10-09Z"));
System.out.println(offsetDateTime("2021-10-09[Australia/Melbourne]"));
System.out.println(offsetDateTime("2021-10-09T08:00:01.111[Australia/Melbourne]"));
System.out.println(offsetDateTime("2021-10-09T08:00:01[Australia/Melbourne]"));
System.out.println(offsetDateTime("2021-10-09T08:00[Australia/Melbourne]"));
System.out.println(offsetDateTime("2021-10-09T08[Australia/Melbourne]"));
System.out.println(offsetDateTime("2021-10-09[Australia/Melbourne]"));
```

```
2021-10-09T08:00:01.111111100Z
2021-10-09T08:00:01.111Z
2021-10-09T08:00:01Z
2021-10-09T08:00Z
2021-10-09T08:00Z
2021-10-09T00:00Z
2021-10-09T00:00+11:00
2021-10-09T08:00:01.111+11:00
2021-10-09T08:00:01+11:00
2021-10-09T08:00+11:00
2021-10-09T08:00+11:00
2021-10-09T00:00+11:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I once had to deal with parsing dates from Strings that could come in ANY format not known in advance. I resolved it in the following way. I prepared a config file that contained on each line a date format that I wanted to support. When String came I tried to parse it with each format from the file until I succeeded or went through all available formats. Note that in this case the order of the formats is important as if you want European formats take precedence over US one you would place European formats first or vise-versa. In any case, I wrote a small article where I explained this idea in detail: [Java 8 java.time package: parsing any string to date](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/java-8-javatime-package-parsing-any-string-date-michael-gantman/)